# Twenty Eleven Child theme error when attempting to use a rewritten function

Tags: functions, child-theme, fatal-error, function-exists

I attempted to make a minor change to a function in the Twenty Eleven theme (wordpress 3.4.2)

I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare twentyeleven_widgets_init() (previously declared in /home/labfocus/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/functions.php:10) in /home/labfocus/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 438
```

Here is the function that I am attempting to add in place of the original

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('twentyeleven_widgets_init')) {
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas. Also register the default Ephemera widget.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
function twentyeleven_widgets_init() {

    register_widget( 'Twenty_Eleven_Ephemera_Widget' );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="su-spoiler-title">%2$s</div><aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside></div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Showcase Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'description' => __( 'The sidebar for the optional Showcase Template', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area One', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-3',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area Two', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-4',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area Three', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-5',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this function?

**Update:** the question is really that I want to change how the `Main Sidebar` displays `before_widget` and `after_widget`. I've added a `<div>`

Comment: I just saw a note in [this article for creating twenty eleven child themes](http://theme.fm/2011/07/how-to-create-a-child-theme-based-on-twenty-eleven-791/) that uses `add_action` and `add_filter` - would these help?

Answer (score 3):

Why exactly are you trying to redeclare that function?

You can either edit the original function, or, better yet, use [remove_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to remove `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyeleven_widgets_init' );` and then reattach your own function `add_action('widgets_init', 'your_widgets_init_function' );`

Comment: Don't edit parent theme, but adding own function is the way to go. Original is coded to be pluggable (able to be declared in different place).

Comment: I want to modify the `Main Sidebar` and this is the only thing I could think of. Is there a way to change `before_widget` and `after_widget` without redoing the whole function?

Comment: @paulruescher I had read in multiple places (including the WP codex) that the correct procedure for a child theme was to use the `if(!function_exists())` structure. I welcome any other methods.

Comment: I just found [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/functionsphp-will-not-work-with-child-theme) that indicates that some twentyeleven functions lack the `if(!function_exists())` code required for the trick to work. @paulruescher can you suggest the correct usage of `remove_action` to fix it?

Comment: I would look into trying to do it properly, but personally what I would do is use remove_action.  In functions.php, there is an add_action right below `twentyeleven_widgets_init`.  Use the first paramater passed in your remove_action.  Then, write your new `twentyeleven_widgets_init`, and use add_action to re-add the function using that original add_action parameter

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... SOLUTION: http://venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions
but use 'after_setup_theme' instead of 'init' or it won't work because the child functions.php is called before the parent functions.php. 
Another useful article: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-protip-child-themes/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.